# scrabble score c++ by searching for a word

Tags: c++, search

I have made a code to get the scrabble score of a word it is working without any complie errors but when i enter a word it doesnt give me the correct scrabble score.

```
vector <char> scrabbleLetters = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
vector <int> scrabblePoints =   { 1,   3,  3,  2,  1,  4,  2,  4,  1,  8,  5,  1,  3,  1,  1,  3,  10,  1, 1,  1,  1,  4,  4,  8,  4,  10 };

void scrabble(string & search)
{
    
    cout << "You scored " << score(search) << " points for that word!" << endl;
}
int score(string s)
{
    int points = 0;
    int lengths = sizeof(scrabbleLetters) / sizeof(char);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lengths; j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
                points += scrabblePoints[j];
        }
    }
    return points;
}
void searchs()
{
    string search = "none";
    

    cout << '\n' << "Enter word : " << endl;
    cin >> search;
    scrabble(search);
}
int main()
{
   searchs();
}
```

when i enter the word function it gives me a score of 11 but it should be 13

```
Enter word :
function
You scored 11 points for that word!
```

`f=4, u=1, n=1, c=3, t=1, i=1, o=1, n=1 == 13`

but for something like gappp, cap it gives me the correct score

can i know why this is happening please

Comment: When i run this code and type :"function" :  i got 13 points !

Comment: you incorrectly checks length of `std::vector` here:
`int lengths = sizeof(scrabbleLetters) / sizeof(char);`
this is for C arrays, here we have std::vector::size() methode

Answer (score 2):

The problem  is the sizeof should not be applied to vectors

I copied into an IDE and ran the code example.  When I found the loop in score

```
int lengths = sizeof(scrabbleLetters) / sizeof(char);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lengths; j++)
    {
        if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
            points += scrabblePoints[j];
    }
}
```

I noticed length was 16, not 26.  so sizeof( a vector) is not its valid data.  use `size`

The code thus ignores the end of the vector, not scoring for 'u' or 't'

Fixed version of the function

```
int score(string s)
{
    int points = 0;
    int lengths = scrabbleLetters.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lengths; j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == scrabbleLetters[j])
                points += scrabblePoints[j];
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

Separating the two arrays is less good than binding them together.....  Creating a structure to hold information, such as number of tiles with the value would probably be useful.  Here is an alternative map to give you some clues.

```
std::map< char, int > scrabbleMap = {
    { 'a', 1},
    { 'b', 3 },
    { 'c', 3 },
    { 'd', 2 },
    { 'e', 1 },
    { 'f', 4 },
    { 'g', 2 },
    { 'h', 4 },
    { 'i', 1 },
    { 'j', 8 },
    { 'k', 5 },
    { 'l', 1 },
    { 'm', 3 },
    { 'n', 1 },
    { 'o', 1 },
    { 'p', 3 },
    { 'q', 10 },
    { 'r', 1 },
    { 's', 1 },
    { 't', 1 },
    { 'u', 1 },
    { 'v', 4 },
    { 'w', 4 },
    { 'x', 8 },
    { 'y', 4 },
    { 'z', 10 }
};


int score(string s)
{
    int points = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        auto res = scrabbleMap.find(s[i]);
        if (res != scrabbleMap.end()) {
            points += res->second;
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

The alternative score shows how the search on a map can be done faster.